# Golang XML: unmarshal ignores namespace

Tags: go

I'm implementing a service in our Go system that reads data from an external SOAP service. Now that I'm writing tests for it, I run into this issue:

```
unable to unmarshal request body for testing: expected element type <soapenv:Envelope> but have <Envelope>
```

If I dump my data, I have this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v2 [...]
```

So I do have the correct namespace in the XML. For the record, this is the struct into which I'm trying to unmarshal the data:

```golang
type collectRequestXML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"soapenv:Envelope"`
    SoapEnv string   `xml:"xmlns:soapenv,attr"`
    XMLNs   string   `xml:"xmlns:v2,attr"`
    Header  struct{} `xml:"soapenv:Header"`
    Body    struct {
        [...]
    }
}
```

What can I do to make the unmarshal fail?

See [this Playground item for reference](https://play.golang.org/p/0ee2RpL2c7P).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the XML package does not write enough about the namespaces. The parsing is very simple. There is a small support for the namespaces. It can parse the XML, but when you create XML ist does not support the namespace thing enough.

Your struct works, when you remove the namespace information inside the `XMLName` definition:

```
type myStruct struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    SoapEnv string   `xml:"xmlns:soapenv,attr"`
    Header  struct{} `xml:"soapenv:Header"`
    Body    struct {
        MyData string `xml:"my-data"`
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/UppXwx0X0i9

Comment: Hey, apxp! Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I'm aware of that, but in that case, the namespace will be missing if you marshal an object into XML, as per [this Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lJP-410mNCA). So if I use that implementation, it stops working in the other direction instead.

Comment: You are right. But that package is just a simple implementation of a XML parser. I think the namespace does not work correct for generating XML. For complex XML definitions I use text templates. I know that this is not perfect, but it is the fastest way to code complex XML generators. AND BIG PLUS ist is very easy to read.