# Trouble accessing namespaced XML attribute with unmarshal in Go

Tags: xml, go

I'm having trouble accessing an attribute in a namespaced tag when using umarshal on some XML data. A working example of what I'm trying to accomplish is on line 14 of my code which demonstrates successfully loading the attribute `name` from the `<cpe-item>` tag, into the `Name` field of the `CPE` struct.

However, doing the same thing with a name-spaced tag such as on line 19 (loading the `name` attribute from the `<cpe23: cpe23-item>` tag into the `Name` field of the `CPE23` struct) does not work - no value is found.

I'm failing to see the discrepancy between these two actions and why one fails while the other doesn't.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type CPEs struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"cpe-list"`
    CPEs    []CPE    `xml:"cpe-item"`
}

type CPE struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    CPE23 CPE23  `xml:"cpe23: cpe23-item"`
}

type CPE23 struct {
    Name string `xml:"cpe23: cpe23-item,name,attr"`
}

func main() {

    var cpes CPEs

    contents := `
    <cpe-list xmlns:meta="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cpe-23="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3" xmlns="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0" xmlns:config="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1" xmlns:ns6="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary-extension_2.3.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary_2.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.1/cpe-dictionary-metadata_0.2.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/scap-core_0.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/configuration_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/scap-core_0.1.xsd">
        <cpe-item name="I'm the cpe name!"><!--I can parse this attribute-->
            <title>I'm the title!</title>
            <references>
                    <reference href="https://example.com">Example</reference>
                    <reference href="https://example2.com">Example 2</reference>
             </references>
            <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="CPE 2.3 name!"/><!--I can't parse this attribute-->
            </cpe-item>
    </cpe-list>`

    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(contents), &cpes)

    for i := 0; i < len(cpes.CPEs); i++ {
        fmt.Println("CPE Name: " + cpes.CPEs[i].Name)
        fmt.Println("CPE23 Name: " + cpes.CPEs[i].CPE23.Name)
    }
}
```

**Go playground link** https://play.golang.org/p/eRMrFePDM4K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml) doesn't provide much insight. Compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337517/golang-xml-unmarshal-ignores-namespace) relatively recent question.

However, it is possible to make your code work by simply removing the namespace from the tag of the `CPE23` field:

```
type CPE struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    CPE23 CPE23  `xml:"cpe23-item"`
}

type CPE23 struct {
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
}
```

...or by prefixing the tag name with the **full** namespace, separated by a whitespace:

```
type CPE struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    CPE23 CPE23  `xml:"http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3 cpe23-item"`
}
```

See this [Go Play](https://play.golang.org/p/C_Ah7a9DfVS)

By looking at the source code of the `encoding/xml` package, it's possible to see that the tokenizer reads an xml element tag in the form of `<ns:foo>`, where `xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace.com"`, into an `xml.Name` struct in the form:

```
xml.Name{
    Space: "http://mynamespace.com",
    Local: "foo"
}
```

And then it resolves tags on your destination struct based on those two fields. If there's no namespace on your struct tag, it matches on the value of `Local` only.